# Include devise mailer in own gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise-confirmable

I am trying to add devise dependency in my gem. By adding

```
gem.add_dependency "devise"
```

and Include modules :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :lockable, :validatable

While running specs from my gem to create user, it throws "uninitialized constant Devise::Mailer".

Please help me

Comment: Do you have a line like `require 'devise'` in your project?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Devise wiki, [How to use Devise Inside a Mountable Engine](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine):

…add the following line to your **lib/name_of_engine.rb**:

```
require 'devise'
```

Otherwise, the Devise::Engine does not initialize within your engine/gem.